# VLC Sideplayer a la Skype

Tags: vlc-media-player, skype

I am looking to see if VLC has an option where I can create mini player that can be dragged around just like the Skype minimal window where I can talk to another person but continue working with other windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I create [a vlc] mini player that can be dragged around?

1. Right click > Video > Always on top
2. Resize window to taste
3. Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>  to select Minimal Interface

[image]

The above video is a [1280x720 test video](http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_30mb.mp4) downloaded from http://www.sample-videos.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can download VLC from windows app store ( i think you need win10 )

it looks like this
[preview of the mini VLC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHfFa.png)

if you like it.
you can download it from [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH4VVNH)

and you can do it from here
[how to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TN5fn.png)